# Replace a part of a file by a part of another file

Tags: bash, replace

I have two files containing a lot of floating numbers. I would like to replace one of the floating numbers from file 1 by a floating number from File 2, using lines and characters to find the numbers (and not their values).

A lot of topics on the subject, but I couldn't find anything that uses a second file to copy the values from.

Here are examples of my two files:

**File1:**

```
  14    4
2.64895E-01  4.75834E+02  2.85629E+05  -9.65829E+01
2.76893E-01  8.53749E+02  4.56385E+05  -7.65658E+01
6.25576E-01  5.27841E+02  5.72960E+05  -7.46175E+01
8.56285E-01  4.67285E+02  5.75962E+05  -5.17586E+01
```

**File2:**

```
Some text on the first line
1
Some text on the third line
0
AND01  0.53758275  0.65728944
AND02  0.64889566  0.53386002
AND03  0.65729386  0.64628194
AND04  0.26586960  0.46582925
AND05  0.46480534  0.57415869
```

In this particular example, I would like to replace the first number of the second line of File1 (2.64895E-01) by the second floating number written on line 5 of File2 (0.65728944).

Note: the value of the numbers will change according to which file I consider, so I have to identify the numbers by their positions inside the files.

I am very new to using bash scripts and have only use "sed" command till now to modify my files.

Any help is welcome :)
Thanks a lot for your inputs!

Comment: I think you might have to graduate from bash and use a real language to read from and write the appropriate field

Comment: how do you identify the positions of the replaced number and replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not hard to do it in `bash`, but if that's not a strict requirement, an easier and more concise solution is possible with an actual text-processing tool like `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==5 {val=$2}  NR>FNR {FNR==2 && $1=val; print}' file2 file1
```

Explanation: read `file2` first, and store the second field of the 5th record in variable `val` (the first part: `NR==5 {val=$2}`). Then, read `file1`, print every line, but replace the first field of the second record (`FNR` is current-file record number, and `NR` is total number of records in all files so far) with value stored in `val`.

In general, an `awk` program consists of `pattern { actions }` sequences. `pattern` is a condition under which a series of `actions` will get executed. `$1`..`$NF` are variables with field values, and each line (record) is split into fields on the field separator (`FS` variable, or `-F'..'` option), which defaults to a space.

The result (output):

```
  14    4
0.53758275 4.75834E+02 2.85629E+05 -9.65829E+01
2.76893E-01  8.53749E+02  4.56385E+05  -7.65658E+01
6.25576E-01  5.27841E+02  5.72960E+05  -7.46175E+01
8.56285E-01  4.67285E+02  5.75962E+05  -5.17586E+01
```

Comment: Thanks randomir, this works perfectly. Very useful text-processing tool, will remember it. Thanks again for your help!